# ODP.Net Driver Throwing Exception on .NET Core 5.0

Tags: oracle, odp.net-managed, .net-5

I am trying to port my database application from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET Core 5.0.

When running the following code,

```
        public async Task<List<T>> LoadDataFromSQL<T, U>(string sql, U parameters, string connectionStringName)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(await GetConnectionString()))
            {
                var rows = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql,
                                                          parameters,
                                                          commandType: CommandType.Text);
                return rows.ToList();
            }
        }
```

I get this exception:

> "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.\r\n ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl' threw an exception.\r\n ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.TimeStamp' threw an exception.\r\n ---> System.NotSupportedException: BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.\r\n   at OracleInternal.Common.OracleTimeZone.GetInstance()\r\n   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.TimeStamp..cctor()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.TimeStamp.InitializelatestTZversion()\r\n   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl..cctor()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl..ctor()\r\n   --- End of inner except
> ion stack trace ---\r\n"

Is is possible to work around this from my application?

I am using the latest version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.91, release on 10/22/2020.  Also, I am using Dapper 2.0.35.

Comment: If you check the link in the error message you'll see that `The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing.`. Oracle shouldn't be using it at all. Obsoleting and removing that type was a target since .NET Core 1.0 [and the .NET team started disabling it in .NET 5.0](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/141). You'll have to wait for Oracle to fix the vulnerability in its client. Or find a better one. ODP has always been rather fat, slow and very quirky when it comes eg to locales and codepages

Comment: There's a 19.10 update that should fix it https://medium.com/@alex.keh/announcing-odp-net-19-10-release-new-net-5-and-bulk-copy-support-be6f395155c9

Comment: Problem still the same 2.19.100 and .net 5, but works with .net Core 3.1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I discovered that Oracle is working on a fix for this which should be available soon.

In the meantime, in case anyone runs into this issue there is a workaround.

In your project file, you can add the XML statement to EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it caused another exception of {"The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception."} Innerexception is {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}. Adding System.DirectoryServices.Protocols v5.0.0 resolved the issue.

Comment: First of all, thanks Jason. 
@Yongkee: You just have to install via Nuget System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21 fixes the issue completely so no need in unsafe binary serialization.