# EXO PowerShell V2 Module remote session Cryptography.SHA256Cng error with .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, exchange-server, .net-5

Trying to implement Exchange Online Remote PowerShell (using the most recent EXO PowerShell V2 module) with C# in a .NET 5.0 project. I used Basic Authentication in the past and have opted to switch to Cert Based Authentication for the non-interactive scripts. Background wise, I have the Azure application and certificate all set up and working.

Following the guidance below, I am able to manually connect using a PowerShell prompt.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/modern-auth-and-unattended-scripts-in-exchange-online-powershell/ba-p/1497387

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

As a small test, these commands all work fine (either using the thumbprint or the .pfx directly):

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbprint "" -AppId "" -Organization ""
Get-EXOMailbox -Identity ""
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

I used this remote runspace example as a base and tried to modify it to perform the same commands via C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/creating-remote-runspaces?view=powershell-7.1

```
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    remoteRunspace.Open();

    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
        powershell.AddCommand("Import-Module");
        powershell.AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement");
        powershell.Invoke();

        powershell.Commands.Clear();

        powershell.AddCommand("Connect-ExchangeOnline");
        powershell.AddParameter("AppId", "");
        powershell.AddParameter("CertificateThumbprint", "");
        powershell.AddParameter("Organization", "");
        powershell.Invoke();

        powershell.Commands.Clear();

        powershell.AddCommand("Get-EXOMailbox");
        powershell.AddParameter("Identity", "");
        powershell.Invoke();

        Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

        powershell.Commands.Clear();

        powershell.AddCommand("Disconnect-ExchangeOnline");
        powershell.Invoke();
    }

    remoteRunspace.Close();
}
```

In the project, I am using all of the latest NuGet packages as far as I know.

`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` 7.1.1
`System.Management.Automation` 7.1.1
`.NET 5.0` for target framework

This error occurs on the second `powershell.Invoke()` line with the Connect-ExchangeOnline command.

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: 'Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....'.. '
```

Including the `UseWindowsPowerShell` parameter for the Import-Module did not help. If I remove the lines associated with `Connect-ExchangeOnline`,  an error mentions to use that command before `Get-EXOMailbox`, so the module seems to be importing correctly at least.

Have been unable to find an updated C# example or guidance from Microsoft. Are there different NuGet packages I should be using, or is there something else I am missing? Better way to do this?

Would appreciate any insight, thanks!

**Edit**: Including a few somewhat related links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/236631/could-not-load-type-39systemsecuritycryptographysh.html

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/503#issuecomment-670676511

**Edit 2**: Went back and made sure I had version `2.0.4-Preview2` of the module installed since that is the only one with PowerShell Core support. No cryptography error after updating to the preview, but still erroring on the same line.

```
Inner Exception 1:
PSRemotingDataStructureException: An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.

Inner Exception 2:
NotSupportedException: BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, getting data back in the `results` object now.

Here is some info on [setting up the Azure app and creating a self-signed certificate.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)

There were a few other things that needed to be done:

1. Make sure you are using a version of the module that supports PowerShell Core. It is currently in preview and you need `2.0.4-Preview2`. [PowerShell Core support in the EXO V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#powershell-core-support-in-the-exo-v2-module).

   I ended up doing the following steps to make sure I had the correct version, close all prompts and then open an administrator PowerShell prompt:

   `Uninstall-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement` and close the prompt.

   `Install-Module PowerShellGet –Repository PSGallery –Force` in a new prompt, then close.

   `Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.4-Preview2 -AllowPrerelease`

   `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement; Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` to confirm.
2. Not sure why this worked, but followed an exception and landed on [this separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790197/odp-net-driver-throwing-exception-on-net-core-5-0).

In the project file, I did the same as that accepted answer.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And that was it.. nothing different in the code, did not have to add `UseWindowsPowerShell`.